# “Sinbad” vs. “Sindbad”?

Tags: difference, pronunciation, spelling, history

In Arabic, I see it written and pronounced as "Sindbad", but "Sinbad" seems to be the original one.

How should we write/pronounce it, *"Sinbad"* OR *"Sindbad"*?

Comment: Wikipedia mentions both spellings, so I guess we can use either of them.

Comment: This question has also been asked on EL&U http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/292347/sinbad-vs-sindbad, I think there are rules against the practice of cross posting.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't seen Sindbad in an English language context before. Sinbad seems to be the default form in English.

Comment: I agree that "Sinbad" is much more common, but Wikipedia does say the original is " السندباد البحري as-Sindibādu al-Baḥriyy", so "Sindbad" is arguably more correct.  In practice, yeah, "Sinbad" is probably going to surprise fewer people.

Comment: Regarding naming in academia, correctness takes second place to consistency. It's a lot harder to change everything to the correct form than to keep using the old close enough form.